# Buttons design like in Jeepsing

Tags: java, android, iphone, android-layout

I'm trying to create buttons in Android the same way as in Jeepsing application for iPhone using linear layout but without success. Maximum that I get is three separated buttons the same size.
I need three buttons without background, separated only by their borders when two of them have one rounded corner like on the following screenshot:

[image]

This is my last try:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button05" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button06" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried GridLayout but without success.

Comment: are you talking about footer ? or save , change and send buttons ?

Comment: can  you provide me the buttons which you have ?

Comment: Yes this is about three buttons above the map. They have to be without any background only with borders. I'm also found that this could be achieved using "shape". Checking this now.

Comment: yeah... you can dynamically set the round cornet like button in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved it:

up_left_button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_left_button_shape_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_left_button_shape_pressed"
      android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_left_button_shape_released" />
</selector>
```

up_left_button_shape_pressed.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#ff0000ff"
    android:endColor="#ff0000ff"
    android:angle="45"/>
<padding android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" 
  android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff444444"/>
</shape>
```

up_center_button_shape_released.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#00000000"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>
<padding android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" 
  android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff444444"/>
</shape>
```

- Center and right button shapes are the same, just need to play with which corners to round.

And finally the view layout:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/buttonsRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/buttonsRowRelativeLayout" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/up_left_button_selector"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerButton" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/centerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/change"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/up_center_button_selector" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/up_right_button_selector"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerButton" />
    </RelativeLayout >      
</TableRow>
```

And it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

just create shapes with corners radius for both pressed/released effects..

```
<solid android:color="#77000000" />

<corners android:radius="10dip" />

<gradient
    android:angle="-90"
    android:endColor="#44FF0000"
    android:startColor="#CCFF0000" />

<padding
    android:bottom="10dip"
    android:left="10dip"
    android:right="10dip"
    android:top="10dip" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="#000000" >
</stroke>
```

for more info about shapes refer [this](http://android-dev-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.in/2012/08/xml-drawables-part-i.html)

After creating shapes for pressed/released effects create a XML file for button selector like following example

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/prs_arrival_fb_btn" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/prs_arrival_fb_btn" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrival_fb_content_btn" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

then set this selector to your button as background.. like the following example..

```
<Button android:text="Play" android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```